# Extracting a content from HTML using regex in python

Tags: python, html, regex

i have this HTML code

```
<a class="button block left icon-phone" data-reveal="\u06f0\u06f9\u06f3\u06f6\u06f5\u06f6\u06f8\u06f1\u06f6\u06f2\u06f1"  href="#">
```

this a sting, i want to extract content in front of *data-reveal*.
i did some regex like

```
p = re.compile('data-reveal=*')
```

but they didn't work. How can i do it ?
Thanks.

Comment: everything in front of data reveal, including href="#"? Can you post your exact desired outcome?

Comment: [BS4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is a better option for this..

Comment: `data-reveal="([^"]*)"` if you want just data within `data-reveal`

Answer (score 3):

You are using [the wrong tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) for this. You should use an Html Parser like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> doc = """<a class="button block left icon-phone" data-reveal="\u06f0\u06f9\u06f3\u06f6\u06f5\u06f6\u06f8\u06f1\u06f6\u06f2\u06f1"  href="#">"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')
>>> print(soup.find('a').get('data-reveal'))
۰۹۳۶۵۶۸۱۶۲۱
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use regex for this but I'll assume you want to since that's what you do in the op. I'm not exactly sure what you want, so here's how to do either of what I think you could be asking

```
match everything in data-reveal:
data-reveal="(.+?)"
matches: \u06f0\u06f9\u06f3\u06f6\u06f5\u06f6\u06f8\u06f1\u06f6\u06f2\u06f1

match EVERYTHING in front of data-reveal
data-reveal="(.+)
matches: \u06f0\u06f9\u06f3\u06f6\u06f5\u06f6\u06f8\u06f1\u06f6\u06f2\u06f1"  href="#">
```

first regex: https://regex101.com/r/jW9fT4/1

second regex: https://regex101.com/r/uZ7vX2/1

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import re

html = """<a class="button block left icon-phone" data-reveal="\u06f0\u06f9\u06f3\u06f6\u06f5\u06f6\u06f8\u06f1\u06f6\u06f2\u06f1"  href="#">"""

regexObj = re.compile('data-reveal="(.*)" ')
result = regexObj.search(html);
print(result.group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
۰۹۳۶۵۶۸۱۶۲۱
```

Comment: hi ren, thanks for your answer alot. now when i print the out put it shows utf-8 (\u06f0\u06f9\u06f3\u06f6\u06f5\u06f6\u06f8\u06f1\u06f6\u06f2\u06f1) how can i convert it to plain that shows ۰۹۳۶۵۶۸۱۶۲۱ ? thanks again.

Comment: thanks, i figure it out, i should use b'\u06f0\u06f9\u06f3\u06f6\u06f5\u06f6\u06f8\u06f1\u06f6\u06f2\u06f1'